# Using MongoDBCompass, how do I search for documents with two consecutive elements in an array field?

Tags: mongodb, filter, mongodb-compass

I have a Mongo collection with an array

```
"auditTrail"
```

that contains objects that may have a field named

```
"command"
```

Using MongoDBCompass (on Windows 10), how do I search for documents that have two consecutive elements in the "auditTrail" that have a "command" with the value "DELETE"?  So for example, this would match

```
{
    "auditTrail": [
        { "executionDate": "2022-01-01",
          "command": "DELETE" },
        { "executionDate": "2022-02-02",
           "command": "DELETE" }
    ]
}
```

but this would not

```
{
    "auditTrail": [
        { "executionDate": "2022-01-01",
          "command": "ADD" },
        { "executionDate": "2022-02-02" }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Something like this? https://mongoplayground.net/p/YXOgKOBHHko  should be able to try aggregation pipeline on compass

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of ways to do.  Here's one way using a single `"$match"` stage.  See below for a slightly *"simplified"* `"$match"` stage.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      "$expr": {
        "$anyElementTrue": {
          "$map": {
            "input": {"$range": [0, {"$subtract": [{"$size": "$auditTrail"}, 1]}]},
            "in": {
              "$and": [
                {
                  "$eq": [
                    {"$arrayElemAt": ["$auditTrail.command", "$$this"]},
                    "DELETE"
                  ]
                },
                {
                  "$eq": [
                    {"$arrayElemAt": ["$auditTrail.command", {"$add": ["$$this", 1]}]},
                    "DELETE"
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Try it on [mongoplayground.net](https://mongoplayground.net/p/u1KngKIEET-).

Here's a slightly *"simplified"* `"$match"` stage that works too.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      "$expr": {
        "$anyElementTrue": {
          "$map": {
            "input": {"$range": [0, {"$subtract": [{"$size": "$auditTrail"}, 1]}]},
            "in": {
              "$eq": [
                {"$slice": ["$auditTrail.command", "$$this", 2]},
                ["DELETE", "DELETE"]
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Try this on [mongoplayground.net](https://mongoplayground.net/p/T_xl4aDlnmd).